# What does "We’re away from next week for the rest of the year, and then for a month" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Just a very quick note – **we’re away from next week for the rest of the year, and then for a month soon after we get back**, so utterly completely submerged in getting organised and working through several business issues.

What does the sentence in boldface mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a point in time (next week) until another point in time (the end of the year) they will be away.  And then from yet another point in time (soon after their return from being away) they will be away for an additional month.

As a result of this schedule:

... so [we are] utterly submerged ...